# how to avoid use of multiple use of if condition in react or ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to verify the data object property and their values.

i tried the below approach instead of writing if else.

```
let data = {name: "aa", phone: 1, email: "", address: "", age: 0, 
     gender: " "}

let selectedmemberStatus = true;
if(data.name == "" || data.name.length < 2) selectedmemberStatus = 
    false;
if(data.phone == "") selectedmemberStatus = false;
if(data.email == "") selectedmemberStatus = false;
if(data.address == "" || data.address.length < 3) 
   selectedmemberStatus = false;
if(data.age == "" || data.age == 0) selectedmemberStatus = false;
if(data.gender == "") selectedmemberStatus = false;
```

Suggest the best approach to minimise the code. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be more readable and flexible to move this logic to a separate function as shown below:

```js
_hasValidMemberStatus(data) {
  const {
    name,
    phone,
    email,
    address,
    age,
    gender,
  } = data;
  const hasCorrectName = !!name && name.length > 1;
  const hasCorrectPhone = !!phone;
  const hasCorrectEmail = !!email;
  const hasCorrectAddress = !!address && address.length > 2;
  const hasCorrectAge = !!age && age !== 0;
  const hasCorrectGender = !!gender;

  return (
    hasCorrectName &&
    hasCorrectPhone &&
    hasCorrectEmail &&
    hasCorrectAddress &&
    hasCorrectAge &&
    hasCorrectGender
  );
}

const data = { name: 'aa', phone: 1, email: '', address: '', age: 0, gender: ' ' };
const selectedMemberStatus = _hasValidMemberStatus(data);
```